# sum rows value based on condition in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: df]

Hello Community,

in my dataframe i have three columns as follow:

restaurant_id, annee, moyenne_etoile_annee.

for each restaurant_id i would like to substract the "moyenne_etoiles_annee' of the last year minus the one from the first year.

By example for the first restaurant_id
df[diff]=moyenne_etoiles_annee(2017)-moyenne_etoiles_annee(2015)
2-2.66=-0.66

I tried to .agg and select first and last value but wasn't able to execute properly.

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"restaurant_id": [1,1,2,2],
                   "annee": [2015,2016,2019,2022],
                   "moyenne_etoile_annee": [1.2,1.4,1.3,1.3]})
```

Comment: Please post the data as code (text) so it's easy for us to copy to test a  possible solution.  Good job though, on giving us input and expected output, and explain what you tried.

Comment: i just created  some sample data replicating

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,1,2,2], "B": [2015,2016,2019,2022],"C": [1.2,1.4,1.3,1.3]})

print (df)

Comment: @Aris - Super, added to quetion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution working well if unique years per `restaurant_id` like in question data.

First use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) per both columns (if necessary) for first and last `annee` per `restaurant_id`, then subtract `first` and `last` value per `restaurant_id` in [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df1 = df.sort_values(['restaurant_id','annee'])
g = df1.groupby('restaurant_id')['moyenne_etoile_annee']
df1['diff'] = g.transform('last').sub(g.transform('first'))
```

Alternative with lambda function:

```
df1 = df.sort_values(['restaurant_id','annee'])
g = df1.groupby('restaurant_id')['moyenne_etoile_annee']
df1['diff'] = g.transform(lambda x: x.iat[-1] - x.iat[0])
```

Comment: if the data frame has duplicate rows for the same year then we won't get proper results

Comment: @Jethen - hmmm, your answer has same problem.

Comment: i just tested the first solution and it worked. Perfect thanks

Comment: @Jethen - So if there are duplicated year per `restaurant_id` there is same problem - not seelcted first and last value. If you think my solution not working per `restaurant_id` then you are wrong, because using `groupby`